# Spring: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I don't know why I keep getting this error repeatedly when ever I launch my spring application. This is the stacktrace of the error

```
 SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5193)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my web.xml file where I have defined the springsecurityfilterchain

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In a file called appconfig-security.xml I have this configuration

```
<http auto-config="true">
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>
```

**EDITTED TO ADD MORE INFO**

this is my appconfig-mvc.xml where I have definitions such as internalviewresolver and other kind of configuration

```
<!-- DataSource definition -->
    <import resource="appconfig-data.xml" />


    <!-- added this line of code -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <!-- ends here -->


    <!-- Mapping Controllers -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springfoundation" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:validation</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- removed internal view resolver from this file -->
<!-- JSP Templates and Pages -->
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

this is my appconf-data.xml file where I have configurations such as database connections

```
<!-- Configure the data source bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springfoundation.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!--
      Configure Spring Data JPA and set the base package of the
      repository interfaces
    -->

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.springfoundation.repository"/>
```

this is how I am importing my configuration xml files defined in spring folder under resource to my web.xml file and also showing the **complete content** in my web.xml file

```
 <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <description>This is a template for a simple and informational Login and CRUD WebAPP.</description>

    <!-- - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context. 
         - Applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/appconfig-mvc.xml, 
            classpath:spring/appconfig-security.xml, 
            classpath:spring/appconfig-root.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


<!-- 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param> -->
<!-- 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/main-dispatcher-servlet.xml, 
            classpath:spring/spring-security-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
-->




    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Servlet that dispatch request from Controllers -->
<!--  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springSimple</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springSimple</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/appconfig-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springSimple</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- General Configurations -->

    <welcome-file-list>
        <!-- First Page load -->
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <!-- No found page -->
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

I dont know why I keep getting this error.

Comment: And what is loading the `appconfig-security.xml`?

Comment: appconfig-root.xml is loading it and appconfig-root.xml is called in the web.xml file

Comment: Xml isn't loading XML. Which class is loading the xml.

Comment: web.xml file is doing that

Comment: Again xml isn;t loading anything... Which **class** is loading your configuration files. Or in other words add your `web.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum the web.xml file is doing that. Please check to see my edits

Comment: Sigh... xml isn't doing anything. xml is xml is just a file it doesn't do or load anything. Again, WHICH class is loading it. Post the `web.xml` NOT a snippet. That request was for a reason...

Comment: I have done that.....

Comment: @M.Deinum are you there?

Comment: Which Spring security version are you using and please add the full stack trace.

Comment: Dont know the version. I have added the complete stacktrace. Do I post my appconfig-security.xml file?

Comment: I doubt that that is the full stack trace.

Comment: Please check that is the complete stacktrace

Comment: Are you including a `servlet-api` jar or another jar in your project that includes the servlet api classes? Also are you sure your file containing the security configuration is actually being loaded?

Comment: It is a maven project.

Comment: Instead of not answering question could you please just answer the question asked...

Comment: Yes I am doing that.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Code as comments is unreadable, improve your question instead.

Comment: Dont get you..... That is a servlet-api.jar that you asked about

Comment: Which is completely garbled and unreadable. As menionted add improvements to your question not as comments. That dependency should at least have `<scope>provided</scope>`. But without seeing al your dependencies not sure if there are more things wrong.

Comment: Are u requesting that I show my pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Please add bean definition in applicationContext.xml like the following.

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>
```

Comment: or,, May be your xml configuration file for Spring Security isn't loaded .. Please add /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml file path in web.xml.
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
</context-param>

Comment: I have this xml files appconfig-mvc.xml, appconfig-security.xml and appconfig-data.xml. So which one of them do I call the above bean?

Comment: I dont have any file called applicationContext.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try the below configuration for springSecurityFilterChain. It worked for me. Note the `<init-param>` for the contextAttribute

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.appServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: Can you paste your complete web.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have the bean definition in applicationContext.xml like following

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy">  
</bean>
```

*ApplicationContext is an xml file which is a container of all bean and its definitions*. Name can be anything other than applicationContext.xml. In your case it might be appconfig-mvc.xml or appconfig-data.xml. Try to post those two xml files 

 **Note:** If you get `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, it means that you have not created the bean definition. 
**Thanks!**

Comment: I have this xml files appconfig-mvc.xml, appconfig-security.xml and appconfig-data.xml. So which one of them do I call the above bean?

Comment: Please which file do mean by applicationContext.xml

Comment: i am doing that hang on

Comment: You should add that line in appconf-data.xml file

Comment: Why not in appconfig-mvc.xml file?

Comment: Yes you can do it in appconfig-mvc.xml file also. sorry i dint notice this file in your edit.